# How do I reverse key value map types on one side of @ManyToMany JPA relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, jpa, mapkeyjoincolumn

I need advice regarding a many-to-many relationship between `KeyStoreEntity` and it's 3 child entities (`KeyPairEntity, SecretKeyEntity, CertificateEntity`). I will use `CertificateEntity` for this example as other 2 follow the same pattern/issue. My extended class `BaseRdbmsEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass` with id, name and description attributes.

I had no problems with `@ManyToMany` on both sides and using `Map<String, CertificateEntity>` on `KeystoreEntity` side to get certificates by their alias along with `Map<String, KeyStoreEntity>` on `CertificateEntity` to get the aliases and associated keystores.

Then I realized I'd blown it as a certificate could easily have the SAME alias in different keystores...thus `CertificateEntity` map keys can clash and one value will wipe out subsequent value stored therein during a repository query.

I need to reverse the key/value types for the map attribute in  `CertificateEntity` to `Map<KeyStoreEntity, String>`. It's unclear to me how I do a `@MapKeyValue` (I realize this doesn't exist) to get alias as value in map...and not as key.

I've attempted to fix the problem by using `@JoinTable` annotations but am not seeing an equivalent of `@MapKeyColumn` for value-side of map. What I want is `KeyStoreEntity` as key and `String alias` as the value.

```java
@Entity(name = "keystores")
@Table(name = "pki_keystores")
public class KeyStoreEntity extends BaseRdbmsSecurityEntity
{
    @MapKeyColumn(name="alias")
    @ManyToMany
    (
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    private Map<String, CertificateEntity> certificates;
    ...snip...
}

@Entity(name = "certificates")
@Table(name = "pki_certificates", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"issuerDn", "serialNumber"})
})
public class CertificateEntity extends BaseRdbmsSecurityEntity
{
    @MapKeyColumn(name="alias")
    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
        mappedBy = "certificates",
        targetEntity = KeyStoreEntity.class
    )
    private Map<String, KeyStoreEntity> keystores;
    // Map type for above needs to be <KeyStoreEntity, String>
    ...snip...
}
```

I'm expecting a lazy fetch to work with k/v reversed on the `CertificateEntity.keystores` side of the relationship. My expectation is I only need to tweak/add an annotation to `CertificateEntity` for `keystores` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of uni/bidirectional relationship Many-to-Many. I hope you would easily adapt it to your code) It's just trivial example with `List`. [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504504/simplest-one-to-many-map-case-in-hibernate-doesnt-work-in-mysql) on SO, too

## @ManyToMany

### `unidirectional`:

#### User.java

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRoles(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void removeRoles(Role role) {
        roles.remove(role);
    }
}
```

#### Role.java

```java
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

### `bidirectional`:

#### Trader.java:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "stockmarkets")
@Table(name = "trader")
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "trader_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trader_name")
    private String traderName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "TRADER_STOCKMARKET",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trader_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "stockmarket_id") })
    private List<Stockmarket> stockmarkets = new ArrayList<>();


    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.add(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.remove(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().remove(this);
    }

}
```

#### Stockmarket.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "traders")
@Table(name = "stockmarket")
public class Stockmarket{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stockmarket_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stockmarket_name")
    private String stockmarketName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarkets")
    private List<Trader> traders = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.add(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.remove(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().remove(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for info but I don't see how this helps me with my case requiring a Map.Entry using an Entity as key and alias as value. There are annotations which exist letting you specify the map key but am unclear on how to get String:alias for the value portion of map.entry tuple.